# Is there any way to switch Xcode versions without using sudo?

Tags: xcode, macos

I have to switch between Xcode versions several times a day for work. I've aliased out the change, but the switch always requires sudo. Is there a way to switch without having to input my password?

I'd like to be able to run the command to switch in the middle of the night (followed by a handful of scripts, etc...), but since the switch requires my password, I can't do it while away.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cat /Users/zrzka/bin/switch-xcode.sh`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

EFFECTIVE_UID=$(id -u)

echo "Effective user ID: ${EFFECTIVE_UID}"
echo "Xcode switching to: $@"
```

&

`cat /etc/sudoers.d/switch-xcode`:

```
zrzka ALL= NOPASSWD: /Users/zrzka/bin/switch-xcode.sh
```

&

`alias switch-xcode="sudo /Users/zrzka/bin/switch-xcode.sh"`

&

```
zrzka@hyrule ~ % switch-xcode foo bar
Effective user ID: 0
Xcode switching to: foo bar
zrzka@hyrule ~ %
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit sudoers ($ sudo visudo) to exclude asking for sudo on xcode-select actions:

```
## No pw for xcode-select
%admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/xcode-select
```

Then, add this to your ~/.bashrc:

```
function switch_xcode () {
    echo "Switching to Xcode: $1"
    sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode_"$1".app // Change this to whatever naming convention you use
    CURRENT_XCODE_VERSION=$(xcode-select -p)
    echo "Current Xcode version: $CURRENT_XCODE_VERSION"
}
```

Then use like so:

```
$ switch_xcode 1.2.3
Switching to Xcode: 1.2.3
Current Xcode version: /Applications/Xcode_1.2.3.app/Contents/Developer
```